# How can I re-initialize my component in Angular 2+ when I navigate to the same url that is open without any changes in route or query parameter?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a left navigation pane where I have a '**Add Item**' link which takes me to a form for adding an item.

My route looks like this :

`{ path: 'additem', component: AddItemComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: {title: 'Add Item'} }`

After the user successfully saves the item, I want to stay on the same page with the save button disabled. However when the user again clicks on the Add Item link in the left nav,I want my component to be re-initialized. How do I do this since the `ngOnInit` method is not invoked if the current view is the one navigated to ? I cannot subscribe to changes in query or route parameters since I have no query or route parameters.

Comment: just wipe the data within the ngmodel (assuming you use one) and then disable the button with a variable?

Comment: are you using formbuilder or formgroup for your form?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using formbuilder for your form,

In your html use `disabled` attribute to disable the button

```
<form [formGroup]="offerForm" (ngSubmit)="addMyOffer(offerForm.value)">
  <input type="text" formControlName="myOffer">
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!offerForm.valid">
     <span>Add</span>
  </button>          
</form>
```

In your component, after saving the data, reset the form to add new offers

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators,FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class formComponent{
  private offerForm:FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){
    this.offerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
       'myOffer' :['',Validators.required],
    });
  }


  private addMyOffer(obj:any){

     //code for saving data      
     this.offerForm.reset(); // resets the form to add new offer

  }
}
```